# Проблема с слушателем ListSelectionListener

Tags: listener, java

Всем привет. У меня возникла проблема с слушателем ListSelectionListener. Мне надо чтобы код работал так: в листе выбирается значение и значение устанавливается в JLabel. Без слушателя код работает, но если вы расскоментируете класс слушателя и метод addListSelectionListener(); ничего работать не будет. Как решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо =) Вот ссылка на код Java 7 http://pastebin.com/n6kcgFSP

Comment: @Роман Кавыршин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
import java.awt.event.*;
```

надо

```
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
```